# Conditional expectation of i.i.d random variables E(X1X2X3|X1)

Tags: random-variables, conditional-expectation

Let X1, X2, . . . , Xn be i.i.d. random variables with E(X1) = 3. What is E(X1X2X3|X1)? (Simplify. Your answer should be a function of X1.)

The solution given is E(X1X2X3|X1) = X1E(X2X3|X1) = X1E(X2)E(X3) = 9X1.

However, I don't understand how to go from the first to second step. Isn't X1 a random variable and are we allowed to take it out like this?

My solution is E(X1X2X3|X1)=E(X1X2X3) = E(X1) E(X2) E(X3)= 3^3 = 27 which is not a function of X1.

Comment: The first equality in your attempt is wrong.

Comment: I thought I could use the same concept as P(X|Y)=P(X) if X and Y are independent.

Comment: $X_1X_2X_3$ and $X_1$ are not independent.

Comment: But X1X2X3 are independent and identical variables, am I applying the wrong concept here?...

Comment: The fact that $X_1,X_2$ and $X_3$ are independent implies for instance that $X_1$ is independent of $X_2$ and similarly that $X_1$ is independent of $X_2 \cdot X_3$, however it does not imply that $X_1$ is independent of $X_1$ and neither does it imply that $X_1$ is independent of $X_1\cdot X_2 \cdot X_3$.